# Output variable property value in Read-Host PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How to output value of a variable property in Read-Host/Powershell

```
@Answer = Read-Host -Prompt "Power Off $VM.Name yes/no"
```

I tried with ($VM.Name) and ($VM).Name which is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Substitute member of variable within string in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235651/substitute-member-of-variable-within-string-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [expand the property](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/) you have to use `$($VM.Name)`

```
Read-Host -Prompt "Power Off $($VM.Name) yes/no"
```